# Roboelectric & Android studio Issues

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, robolectric

I have been trying for hours now to get a simple Roboelectric Test class to compile. All the items in red cannot be found and therefore are throwing compiling errors.

[image]

```
dependencies {
    // Robolectric
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3' // fixes linux/mac
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
}
```

Comment: In which folder is the class? It should be in `src/test/java/<package>`

Comment: I would also keep test in the same package as class under test

Comment: if you can share project layout, flavours then it would be easy to help

Comment: Ah thats the problem, in my Android studio I am not able to create any folders under 'src' except for main or  'androidTest' ---- I can create a folder in windows explorer sure, but android studio does not recognize it.

Comment: If you use 1.x Android studio then take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469190/what-do-i-need-enable-or-install-to-get-the-annotation-runwith/32471024#32471024

Comment: Ah issue # 2.... my build variants window is greyed out and says "Loading...." but nothing ever loads.

Comment: Problem was a deprecated plugin I had installed: android-studio-unit-test-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a deprecated plugin I had installed: android-studio-unit-test-plugin.